# how to redraw the SWT table item using GC withought redrawing other table items?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, paint, rcp

i have SWT table with lots of table item and  I am drawing details  in the table item using  paint Listener evnt.gc.drawText and event.gc.drawImage methods

when i call table.redraw() method the  whole table get redrawn  but i want to redraw only one table item without  affecting other table items

Answer (score 1):

Get the `TableItem` for the item that you want to redraw and use:

```
Rectangle bounds = tableItem.getBounds();

table.redraw(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use PaintListener event.gc for drawing objects, we need to first set bounds to the table using table.setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) option.
If the setBounds option is not used with the objects the paintControl event will not work on them.

```
Canvas canvas = new Group(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
canvasSchema.setBounds(180, 5, 750, 500);   
canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
@Override
public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
if(lstSchemaReq.getSelectionCount() > 0){
    e.gc.drwaOval(100, 40, 50, 50);
  }
 }
});
```